# Inheritance - Include files in an included file

Tags: php, inheritance

I have three files:

- blog.php
- comment.php
- function.php

Inside my blog.php there is an include() for function.php and comment.php.

My question is: is there any way for comment.php to inherit the inclusion of function.php from blog.php, and use its content without declaring the include() function again?

Thanks in advance, for any help.

Comment: php's include is basically a cut&paste thing, as if the contents of the file being included were literally part of the file doing the including.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you include a file, the included file will inherit all code before it's inclusion. If you are including something like this:

***a.php***

```
$foo="bar";
include('b.php');
```

***b.php***

```
include('c.php');
$foobar = $bar." is ".$foo
```

**c.php**

```
$bar = "foo";
```

**d.php**

```
include('a.php');
echo $foobar;
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If function.php is included first it will be available to any code running in comment.php.

However, if comment.php requires function.php to operate correctly, putting an `include_once` at the top of comment.php is a good idea.